# how to get hostname from IP address?

Tags: go

I'm trying to get the hostname from Ip address but I always get error below :

```
 err couln't get hostnames,err lookup 220.220.103.65.in-addr.arpa.: no such host,ip 65.103.220.220
```

The code :

```
var hostname string
hostnames, err := net.LookupAddr(c.ip)
 if err != nil {
  glog.Errorf("err couln't get hostnames,err %v,ip %v", err, c.ip)
  } else {
  hostname = strings.Join(hostnames, " ")
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

That's not an error but a simple statement that the IP address you're looking for has no PTR record. There's no requirement that every machine on the Internet has a PTR record, and no guarantee that trying to find a name from the IP address will succeed.

In short, your code won't always return a name and there's nothing you can do about it.

Whatever it is you're using the machine name for, you can't rely on it. Find a different way.

Comment: nmap actually gets the hostname e.g. `nmap scan report for host81-135-23-115.range81-135.btcentralplus.com (81.135.23.115)` so I'm wondering why go can't do that

Comment: This is not about which tool you use or system call you make. It's about the information available in the world wide DNS. Some addresses will give a response, others won't. It's not in your control and it's not predictable. Don't rely on it.

Comment: The issue is that go never provided any 'response' information. So far I have 2500 IP addresses so I guess there is a Go issue. For the same IP nmap provides hostname while Go doesn't .

Comment: You may take the IP 81.135.23.115  and try it, not my word

Comment: Maybe `nmap` and `Go` are using different resolvers?